# Screen sharing Application with Socket very slow

Tags: java, java-8, screen-capture

I am trying to develop a Screen Sharing application in java and below is the code that capture screen shot

```
public void run() {
    java.awt.image.BufferedImage img = null;
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    javax.swing.ImageIcon icon = null;

    while (true) {
        try {
            img = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
            icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(img);
            os.writeObject(icon);
            os.flush();
            icon = null;
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But its very slow, their is lag of 3-4 Sec, is their any open source API available which i can use ?

Comment: Did you check which operation is slow? Is it the screen capture or the network transfer? How large is your image (MB) when sent over network?

Comment: A `BufferedImage` is not serializable, so what `ImageIcon` does, is extracting the contents into an array to be written to the stream. Sophisticated screen sharing applications track which parts of the screen have really changed, to reduce the image section, then use compression to reduce the amount of data even further. Transferring a full screen image as an array *is* expensive, though I wouldn’t expect 3-4 seconds, on the other hand, we don’t know anything about your network…

Comment: Thanks @Holger this is the exact issues which i am trying to fix, do you have any sample program or do you know any material which i can refer.